# Cant add bmp file to picture control

Tags: image, mfc, controls

I'm trying to add a bmp picture in picture controle in my dialog based app.
So basically I have added picture control in dialog, and I have changed picture control type from frame to bitmap. Picture control ID is IDC_STATIC
After that I added this code in header:
`CStatic* m_picture;`

In project file under OnInitDialog I added this:

`m_picture = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);`

`HITMAP hb = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, L"C:\1.bmp", IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);`

`m_picture->ModifyStyle(0xF, SS_BITMAP, SWP_NOSIZE);`

`m_picture->SetBitmap(hb);`

I don't get any errors, however the app doesn't work, it doesn't display anything...
Am I missing something?

Comment: `IDC_STATIC` is usually assigned to **all** static controls. Your call to `GetDlgItem` may not retrieve the correct one. You should assign a different ID instead. The `0xF` in your call to `ModifyStyle` is awkward as well. You should consider using symbolic constants instead.

Comment: Also, you must double the backslash within quoted literal strings: L"C:\\1.bmp"

Comment: Changing the ID helped,,works like charm..Thank you both.

Comment: @AndrijaGlavas, try to See my Answer, and if this is Correct Give  a +1 So that the user Can easily fetch these answers When they really needed it

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Path is not relevant

### TO add Image to a Picture Control

```
// Declare  CStatic Object
CStatic aDummyImageName;

//On InitFunction

BOOL YourClassName::OnInitDialog()
{ 
aDummyImageName= (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(ID of Your Picture Control);
        HBITMAP dateImage = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, L"Path of the Image",  IMAGE_BITMAP, 225, 170, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
        aDummyImageName->SetBitmap(dateImage);

return TRUE;
}
```

Try This, It Will Work

Answer (score -1):

IDC_STATIC is used for everything that doesn't change. The program can't find it with that. But once you fix that you may have MY problem, which is that Visual studio keeps revising my picture control in *.rc to no longer be "static", and then it won't build. :(